# Why is my CSS not adding what I added to it today on the live server?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my code to work for my html page for class but the parts on my css that I added today are not showing up. Here is the link to the site and css if you anyone could take a look at it and give me some help!

- Carson

http://pages.iu.edu/~ctkeller/i101/css2.html

http://pages.iu.edu/~ctkeller/i101/css2.css

Comment: Hello, Welcome to stack overflow , please read the following  guideline , How to ask a good  question.  link here  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Looks fine to me. What are you expecting to see?

Comment: Also, *please* use meaningful names for CSS classes, for your own sake, when you go to modify the webpage in six months and wonder what `.yeet` was used for again.

Answer (score 4):

This is because your css is cached by your browser. By a hard refresh you can clear the cache.You can learn about hard refresh [here](https://www.wikihow.com/Force-Refresh-in-Your-Internet-Browser).

But you can't ask your clients to hard refresh. So you need to update the version of the css file where the browser will understand it's new version and clear the cache and load the new version itself.

The way of updating the css version is add `?version=version_no` in the css include path.

eg: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css?version=1" />`

Answer (score 0):

Your browser has likely cached an old version of the webpage and CSS. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> to clear the cache for the webpage, and refresh it.